# Dropdown box filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am creating a ASP.NET application using C# and what I want to do is create a filter. For instance, I have 2 drop down boxes

```
countryDropDownBox
stateDropDownBox
```

What I want to do is when I select a country I want to automatically populate the stateDropDownBox, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the autopostback property of the countryDropDownBox control, but can you post some code to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You want a cascading drop down.

The AJAX Toolkit has an example here:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a post back, just set the country drop down list to AutoPostback=true and rebind the state drop down list from the selected value of the country drop down list. Definitely the easiest way.

If you would rather not do a post back, either bind it using either javascript or javascript/ajax call like the others are saying.

Answer (score 1):

On aspx file

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="countryDropDownBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="countryDropDownBox_SelectedIndexChanged"/>

<asp:DropDownList ID="stateDropDownBox" runat="server"/>
```

On aspx.cs file

```
private void countryDropDownBox_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
  string selectedCountry = countryDropDownBox.SelectedItem.Text;
  FillStateDropwDownList(selectedCountry);

}
// I must say that you don't have to use a parameter for that
// you can basically take countryDropDownBox.SelectedItem.Text in the below method
// but I prefer to do that in countryDropDownBox_SelectedIndexChanged because
// selectedCountry actually belongs to countryDropDownBox
private void FillStateDropwDownList(string selectedCountry)
{
 stateDropDownBox.Items.Clear();
 //use selectedCountry for filtering query from database tale or something else
 //use a foreach(I'd prefe for) loop to add the items in the returning string list which contains the states for selected country by stateDropDownBox.Items.Add(item)
}
```