# Adding a Value to a Dropdown List that will trigger an event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a dropdown list being populated with values from a database.  I need to add an additional value in the dropdown to allow the users to add another value.  This new value will be "Add Contact" and if selected will take the user to a new page.  Is this possible to do and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Your title and question body don't make much sense together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DrpDwnLstRecords" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpDwnLstRecords_SelectedIndexChanged"/>

private void FillDrpDwnLstRecords()
{
 DrpDwnLstRecords.Items.Clear();
 ListItem listItem = new ListItem("Add Contact","addContact");
 //fill the dropdown from database here

}

protected void DrpDwnLstRecords_SelectedIndexChanged(..,..)
{
 string selectedRecordValue = DrpDwnLstRecords.SelectValue;
 if(selectedRecordValue == "addContact")
 {
  //go to new page
 }
}
```

For more help with DropDownLists and opening new page

[a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333790/647884)

[DropDownList Web Server Control Declarative Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf(v=VS.90).aspx)

[DropDownList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)

[How to add listitem in dropdownlist using C# behind code.](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/848141-how-add-listitem-dropdownlist-using-c-behind-code)

[DropDownList in ASP .Net](http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/asp-net-articles/dropdownlist-in-asp-net.aspx)

[HOW TO: Add a default ListItem to a DropDownList](http://forums.asp.net/t/1142484.aspx/1)

[Opening a New Window - How to open a new window with JavaScript](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the information @OkayGuy.  I used a combination of both answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can add "Add Contact ... " as a normal text and in the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event of the dropdown (don't remember the exact name of the event), check if the selected value is "Add Contact", call the AddContact() method.

Comment: +1 You're correct about the name.  @Craig be aware you'll need `AutoPostback = true` on the DropDownList in order for this to work properly.

Comment: To add "Add Contact" after you populate the ddl from db. using: `
        ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Add Contact", "itemvalue")) ` or `
        ddl.Items.Insert(x, New ListItem("Add Contact", "itemvalue"))` x is a 0-based int that specify the item index in the ddl.

Comment: Thanks jadarnel27 for the confirmation :)